# Oracle EXPLAIN PLAN FOR Returns Nothing

Tags: sql, oracle, jupyter-notebook

I run the following query on an Oracle database:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
SELECT *
FROM table_name
```

However, it's not returning any data. When I delete the `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR` clause, the query does run as expected. Thanks for the help!

In case it's relevant, I'm accessing the database through Teradata and also a Jupyter IPython notebook.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Using EXPLAIN PLAN](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/ex_plan.htm):

> The PLAN_TABLE is automatically created as a global temporary table to hold the output of an EXPLAIN PLAN statement for all users. PLAN_TABLE is the default sample output table into which the EXPLAIN PLAN statement inserts rows describing execution plans
>
> ```
> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR  SELECT last_name FROM employees;
> ```
>
> **This explains the plan into the PLAN_TABLE table.** You can then select the execution plan from PLAN_TABLE.
>
> ### Displaying PLAN_TABLE Output
>
> - UTLXPLS.SQL
> - UTLXPLP.SQL
> - DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY table function

I suggest to use:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM table_name;

SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but get ORA-933 "SQL command not properly ended". Any advice?

Comment: @Jack This is the next statement. Just run first one end with semicolon, then run next.